# Magento 1.7.0.2: How to remove special price from bundled product items

Tags: magento

I created a few bundled products with several bundled items for each.

A few of these bundled products are on sale with 20% off.

The problem is that if i put the special price of 20% for the bundled item. This is automatically applied also to the bundled items. We don't want the bundled items to include the 20% off. How can I exclude it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, do you want give 20% off to only selected items? If you want to do that, you can create Shopping Cart Price Rules under Promotion Menu tab. First we need to ensure for SKU is already apply or not in promotion. So, got to

1. Catalog Menu -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes
2. Type SKU on Attribute Code Textbox
3. Click for more details
4. Find Use for Promo Rule Conditions on Fronted Properties (default is No)
5. Change to Yes. Then Click to Saves Attributes

Ok, we will go back to Shopping Cart Price Rules.

1. Click on Add New Rule
2. Fill up All require information on Rule Information
3. This part is really important part. Click on Conditions
4. Click on + button and drop down will appear. Choose Product Product attribute combination
5. Then Click to + button. new drop down will appear and you will see SKU. Then, chose SKU.
6. So, you will see like that **SKU is ...**
7. You can paste SKU directly if already know SKU. Otherwise, you can also choose.
8. Final step is Click on Actions. In there, you can set 20% or whatever you want.

I'm not pretty sure for Clear Cache and Index Management. 
Then, you can give 20% to only individual bundeled items.

Comment: Thank you Thiha for the answer. This does indeed helps to apply the discount to bundled product only and not to bundled options.